# has_one belongs_to association autosave => true not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autosave

I have two models

```
Board
has_one    :pref, :autosave => true,  :dependent => :destroy

Pref

belongs_to :board
```

The pref object has defaults that are set in the database so no information needs to be used to create the object when the board is created. The ID for the board is in the pref table.

Since the :autosave=> true I thought that when I create and save a new Board object a pref object would be created and saved automatically.

This is not working this way so I must be misunderstanding.

Is there a way to autosave a pref object when a board is saved?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autosave => true` should not create an element for you. The [docs say](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one):

> If true, always save the associated
>   object or destroy it if marked for
>   destruction, when saving the parent
>   object. If false, never save or
>   destroy the associated object.

You could use a [callback](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_create) to create the `pref` object when you're creating a new `board`.

Something along the lines of:

```
after_create :create_pref

def create_pref
  pref.create!
end
```