# Rails 5 - polymorphic with autosave not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have a Tag model in a polymorphic relationship with Annotation and Document.

**Tag**

`belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true`

**Annotation**

`has_many :tags, :as => :tagable, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true`

**Document**

`belongs_to :tagable, :polymorphic => true, autosave: true`

Yet autosave does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? Do you get an error? Does the creation work? What about the destruction? Also can you share the code you're using to for this?

Comment: does not update/save; what code would you need?

Comment: I'm thinking about the one you use to create objects.

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing and what you want to accomplish. Make sure you're reading these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403372/has-one-belongs-to-association-autosave-true-not-saving, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605120/autosave-ignored-on-has-many-relation-what-am-i-missing and ofc https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/56b3849316b9c4cf4423ef8de30cbdc1b7e0f7af/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L95

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Autosave is not causing the issue; this needs to be implemented using nested forms, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `reject_if`.